# javascript functions- general rules of usage

Tags: javascript, function

Are there any rules I should know about when writing functions in JavaScript
(e.g. Should the function be defined before it is called?)

Comment: Why did i get a negative mark? I tried it a lot. And I am new to JS :(

Comment: It's probably just because it was not worded very clearly. I've reworded it, but it's still not likely to get too much interest as it's quite a vague request. In general, the more detail you can include, the better.

Comment: Thanks Urbycoz, I will try to ask vivid questions.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that this is Javascript in a web page.

The only rule for funcitons in the global scope is that the function has to be in the same or an earlier script block than the code that is initiating the call.

This for example won't work:

```
<script>
doSomething();
</script>

<script>
function doSomething() { alert('something'); }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Function declarations are hoisted, so language rules don't demand a specific order.

However, it is generally considered to be good style to declare functions before calling them as it makes the code clearer.